# Replace a character from a variable and then print

Tags: bash, loops, variables, replace, echo

Hi So I have saved a bunch of variables:

```
fxp0_21_mac = 0A:AA:FF:C1:A1:EE
fxp0_22_mac = 0A:AA:FF:C1:A2:EE
fxp0_23_mac = 0A:AA:FF:C1:B1:EE
fxp0_24_mac = 0A:AA:FF:C1:B2:EE
fxp0_25_mac = 0A:AA:FF:C1:C1:EE
fxp0_26_mac = 0A:AA:FF:C1:C2:EE
fxp0_27_mac = 0A:AA:FF:C1:D1:EE
fxp0_28_mac = 0A:AA:FF:C1:D2:EE``
```

I am trying to loop for each of those variables by replacing the number `21`, for instance in the variable `fxp0_21_mac` into a different number for example `22`

The numbers 21 to 28 are going to be loop in sequence:

```
for ((CN=21;CN<=28;CN++)); do
   
    (for example): x=$(echo fxp0_$CN_mac) 
    echo $x
    #print 0A:AA:FF:C1:A2:EE

done
```

However, I cannot get to print variable itself when changing the middle number.

my expected output:

```
echo $x
#0A:AA:FF:C1:A2:EE
```

my output:

```
echo $x
#fxp0_22_mac
```

Is there a way to change or replace a variable character and print the variable result which in this case would be a MAC ADDRESS?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Do you want to rename a variable? BTW, why do you use 8 individual variables instead of a single associative array, where the key is something like `21` or `22`?

Comment: Dynamic variables names was the solution!